Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS cannot be pinged by computer on network without the Ubuntu server pinging the other computer first
this is a new install on a physical Dell R430 server - not a virtual server.
I change the ip address on Ubuntu to a static ip address and reboot Ubuntu server.
I cannot ping the static ip address of the Ubuntu server from any computer until I ping the other computer's ip address from the Ubuntu server.
the server behaves like the network is asleep until I push a ping out from the server.
my .yaml file looks like this:
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
        - aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
        - aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
        search:
        - domain.net
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
  version: 2

substitute actual addresses for aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd above.
I get the same issue whether I use routes or the old gateway4: parameter

Your "censored" YAML file is nonsense. Is aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd the same everywhere?

This is sounding like a network problem, not an Ubuntu problem. But with that said, you'll need to provide a lot more details on how your network is setup. Is the server on the same subnet as the other computer? Is there a router involved? Can you ping the server from the router and vice versa? etc...

Regarding your censored YAML file, if your server is on a private network, then there is no need to censor those particular IP addresses. As for your nameservers, this could vary depending on whether you're using private or public addresses. If public, I could only see the need to censor a nameserver from your ISP. Other than that, you'd be ok without censoring them.

yaml file:
network:
ethernets:
eno1:
addresses:
- 172.16.16.40/24
nameservers:
addresses:
- 172.16.16.12
- 172.16.16.13
search:
- domain.net
routes:
- to: default
via: 172.16.16.1
version: 2

the machine I am trying to ping the server is on the same network - 172.16.16.20 - same switch
